# Pyqt5: Pixmap color issue

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

It's a QPixmap (in QLabel) on the picture. The thing is: I've connected to my Ubuntu 15.04 from Windows 8.1 by `xrdp` and ran my python app with Pyqt5 gui. Suddenly, seems like there is no red channel (blue cars on the picture are red actually).

No problem when I just run it on Ubuntu. Issue appears both with JPG and PNG. Have someone faced such problem? Suggestions? Thank you!

Python 2.7.9

```
img = '(picture path)'
pixmap = QPixmap(img)
pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(500)
pixmap_label = QLabel(self)
pixmap_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

**Update**

I figured out that it's not a Pixmap problem, but a Qt issue, because I made one button red (with setStyleSheet) and it became blue when I connect from Windows.

**Update**

Yeah, and blue color is red. The reason is, somehow it's not RGB when I connect by `xrdp`, but BGR

**Update**

One possible solution is use QImage.rgbSwapped(), but still it doesn't fix issue with the rest of GUI.

```
image_qt = ImageQt(img)
image_qt = image_qt.rgbSwapped()
img = QImage(image_qt)
pixmap = QPixmap(img)
pixmap = pixmap.scaledToHeight(500)
pixmap_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are hitting [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=487884).

It was submitted upstream (from Debian, where the issue was reported to Qt) in [this message](http://trolltech.com/developer/task-tracker/index_html?method=entry&id=196152).

I suspect you are useing a PowerPC?

Comment: no, I'm using Intel on every laptop. Sorry, link to trolltech.com is broken or something, I see only advs there. I think it's actually the bug you've mentioned, but it's said that bug was fixed in 4.5.2

Comment: @Anatoly Ok... Still, I'm convinced it's a similar problem; maybe you've stumbled upon a new version. Maybe you could print out the values of pixels on the trouble spots, before and after (i.e. in Windows and Ubuntu)

Comment: The BGR/RGB problem is what I was afraid of. This is very related to the answer I gave you before, where the problem came from the exchange between little-endian and big-endian values. There, the colors are stored inverted.